# Unicode in the footer does not wotk

Tags: unicode, footer, postscript

I'm using the following snippet to add a footer to a PDF document.
It works fine, but although I have the UNCODE working in the PDF
document, it does not work in the footer. Otherwise what I ADDED
to the document.

```
gs -q -dNOPAUSE \
  -sDEVICE=pdfwrite \
  -sOUTPUTFILE=output.pdf \
  -c '<< /EndPage \
        { exch pop 0 eq dup \
          { /CharterRegular 10 selectfont \
            /ms {moveto show} bind def \
            (J'aime le café) 40 40 ms \
          } if \
        } bind \
      >> setpagedevice' \
  -dBATCH input.pdf \
```

Any idea?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Another complication is that the `show` operator doesn't handle UTF-8 in postscript strings. You'd need to discover the postscript name for the glyph and use `glyphshow` or build an encoding vector and install it into the font and use the same code in the string.

Comment: Thanks @k-j and @luser-droog for taking time to respond. To start with, I need to educate myself to understand your responses. Yes! Although I'm in publishing business I'm a newbie in postscript domain.
Just to clarify a bit, the main font I use in the document is already fully embedded in the PDF document. The whole book is in French and there's no problem with the accented characters. I have to explore the peculiarity of `show` function and understand what `/F0` and `/F1` mean in @k-j response.
Will come back to say how I go ahead.

Comment: Thanks @k-j. I think I go with my alternative solution using Calibre. I wanted to avoid it because the process takes longer and it generates a bigger PDF file which I have to optimize (using gs). The footer generated by Calibre is fully unicode compatible. I can throw all sort of unicode  characters and I get them in the final doc. Although it forces me to have a longer worflow the solution works fine.
I could use the GS route only for the footer texts exclusively with basic latin chars but I don't like the hack.
I might come back to explore this later.

Answer (score 1):

PDF does not generally use UTF-8 so it should fail as a PostScript command. This use of basic western characters can be a challenge to ensure the font is available or folder is defined or substituted in the fontmap.gs AND possibly Unicode charmap is correctly identified in octal. [One unicode source I found for windows](https://unicode.org/Public/MAPPINGS/VENDORS/MICSFT/WINDOWS/CP1252.TXT) (unsure if 100% relevant) has

`0xE9   0x00E9  #LATIN SMALL LETTER E WITH ACUTE` so in octal that is `\351`

and this "works for me"

**Note** there are windows specific differences but those should be easily Portable, but I used MS Arial for testing. current GS 9.55/9.56 may need `-dNEWPDF=false` and do not use -q until testing is done.

`gswin32c -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dNEWPDF=false -sFONTPATH="C:\Windows\Fonts" -o"french.pdf" -c "<< /EndPage { exch pop 0 eq dup { /Arial 10 selectfont /ms {moveto show} bind def (J'aime le caf\351) 40 40 ms } if } bind >> setpagedevice" -f input.pdf`

[image]

Later edit found an old CharterITCReg.ttf lurking about but note the difference in naming and only found that by trail [sic] and error.

```
gs9.56.1\bin>gs -dNEWPDF=false -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -sFONTPATH=c:\usr\myfonts\ -ofrench.pdf -c "<< /EndPage { exch pop 0 eq dup { /CharterITC-Regu 10 selectfont /ms {moveto show} bind def (J'aime le caf\351) 40 40 ms } if } bind >> setpagedevice" -f in.pdf
```

[image]

Comment: I tried your suggestion adding the two new options you added to the syntax: -sFONTPATH, -dNEWPDF=false, using a group of existing fonts on my system. Using Linux I don't have Arial, but by the font viewer I see the ones I tried have the accented chars. None of them worked. The output remains rigorously the same.
Knowing that it works on Windows puzzles me though. 
Thanks again @k-j

Answer (score 1):

Returning to say that your solution worked for me.
'show' function does not do any Unicode conversion and I had to do it in advance my self. Nothing was wrong with my fonts, which I thought initially as the culprit.
Finally this is how I fixed the problem:

- Picked up the right Unicode bloc for Latin script (Latin-1 Supplement) satisfying my needs ([here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latin-1_Supplement))
- Write a (ruby) function converting on the fly my strings to Unicode strings replacing the accentuated chars with their corresponding code.
- Sending this string to the 'show' function.
- While I was there I added the Even/Odd page aware footer message which I needed.

Here's the final code:

```
<< /EndPage
  { 0 eq dup
    { /Lora-Regular 8 selectfont
      /ms {moveto show} bind def
      exch 2 mod 0 eq
      {
        (J'aime le caf\351 - Even page ) 30 25 ms
      }
      {
        (J'aime toujours le caf\351 - Odd page ) 30 25 ms
      }
      ifelse
    } if
  } bind
>> setpagedevice
```

Here are the Unicode char codes in case it can help somebody:

```
  UNICODE = {
    'â' => { oct: '342', hex: '00E2' },
    'Â' => { oct: '302', hex: '00C2' },
    'à' => { oct: '340', hex: '00E0' },
    'À' => { oct: '300', hex: '00C0' },
    'á' => { oct: '341', hex: '00E1' },
    'Á' => { oct: '301', hex: '00C1' },
    'æ' => { oct: '346', hex: '00E6' },
    'Æ' => { oct: '306', hex: '00C6' },
    'å' => { oct: '345', hex: '00E5' },
    'Å' => { oct: '305', hex: '00C5' },
    'ç' => { oct: '347', hex: '00E7' },
    'Ç' => { oct: '307', hex: '00C7' },
    'é' => { oct: '351', hex: '00E9' },
    'É' => { oct: '311', hex: '00C9' },
    'è' => { oct: '350', hex: '00E8' },
    'È' => { oct: '310', hex: '00C8' },
    'ë' => { oct: '353', hex: '00EB' },
    'Ë' => { oct: '313', hex: '00CB' },
    'ï' => { oct: '357', hex: '00EF' },
    'Ï' => { oct: '317', hex: '00CF' },
    'î' => { oct: '356', hex: '00EE' },
    'Î' => { oct: '316', hex: '00CE' },
    'ì' => { oct: '354', hex: '00EC' },
    'Ì' => { oct: '314', hex: '00CC' },
    'í' => { oct: '355', hex: '00ED' },
    'Í' => { oct: '315', hex: '00CD' },
    'ô' => { oct: '364', hex: '00F4' },
    'Ô' => { oct: '324', hex: '00D4' },
    'ö' => { oct: '366', hex: '00F6' },
    'Ö' => { oct: '326', hex: '00D6' },
    'ó' => { oct: '363', hex: '00F3' },
    'Ó' => { oct: '323', hex: '00D3' },
    'ò' => { oct: '362', hex: '00F2' },
    'Ò' => { oct: '322', hex: '00D2' },
    'õ' => { oct: '365', hex: '00F5' },
    'Õ' => { oct: '325', hex: '00D5' },
    'û' => { oct: '370', hex: '00F8' },
    'Û' => { oct: '330', hex: '00D8' },
    'ù' => { oct: '371', hex: '00F9' },
    'Ù' => { oct: '331', hex: '00D9' },
    'ú' => { oct: '372', hex: '00FA' },
    'Ú' => { oct: '332', hex: '00DA' },
    'ñ' => { oct: '361', hex: '00F1' },
    'Ñ' => { oct: '321', hex: '00D1' },
    'ý' => { oct: '375', hex: '00FD' },
    'Ý' => { oct: '315', hex: '00CD' },
    '®' => { oct: '256', hex: '00AE' },
    '©' => { oct: '251', hex: '00A9' }
  }
```

I kept the Hex values even though I don't use them (for now).

Thanks again @k-j. Seeing that it was working for you, told me that I was wrong in my assumptions blaming the poor fonts.